# Problem with Angular dependencies: @types/node: '{' or ';' expected

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, dependencies

I'm getting an error while executing "ng serve" in my application, it was an Angular 5 application (Angular 2 at the first stage), now I've upgraded it to Angular 8 (Also tried Angular 6 and 7 before).
But after upgrading from Angular 5, I started getting errors while executing "ng serve", the errors usually points to the @types/node, like:

> ERROR in ../node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts:8:68 - error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.

or:

> node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts:56:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'assert'.

I've tried upgrading different packages (Found some suggestions about upgrading some of the @types or Typescript versions in a couple of Github posts), using different versions of Angular/Typescript, updating node (Now version 14.16.1), even removing the @types from the DevDependencies, nothing worked so far.
Maybe I have some deprecated packages/functionallities or even code which is affecting the whole application while using Angular versions >5.

 This is my package.json (Without the @types):

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/common": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/compiler": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/core": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/forms": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/platform-server": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/router": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/upgrade": "8.2.14",
  "angular2-notifications": "2.0.0",
  "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
  "bootstrap-datepicker": "1.6.4",
  "bootstrap-select": "1.13.18",
  "brace": "0.11.1",
  "core-js": "3.0.1",
  "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
  "jquery": "3.4.1",
  "lodash": "4.17.21",
  "ng2-file-upload": "1.4.0",
  "ng2-table": "1.3.2",
  "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
  "rxjs": "6.6.7",
  "rxjs-compat": "6.0.0-rc.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.9.1"

},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.803.29",
  "@angular/cli": "8.3.29",
  "@angular/language-service": "8.2.14",
  "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
  "bestzip": "1.1.4",
  "codelyzer": "5.0.1",
  "copy-webpack-plugin": "3.0.1",
  "css-loader": "0.28.0",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
  "file-loader": "0.11.1",
  "html-loader": "0.4.5",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "2.28.0",
  "jasmine-core": "3.4.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
  "karma": "4.1.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
  "null-loader": "0.1.1",
  "protractor": "5.4.2",
  "raw-loader": "3.1.0",
  "rimraf": "2.7.1",
  "style-loader": "0.23.1",
  "to-string-loader": "1.1.6",
  "ts-loader": "5.4.5",
  "ts-node": "8.3.0",
  "tslint": "5.20.0",
  "tslint-loader": "3.5.4",
  "typescript": "3.4.5",
  "url": "0.11.0",
  "url-loader": "1.1.2"
}
```

Hopefully, someone could have faced a similar situation before and would be able to help me sorting this out, I've seen several posts with issues like this without a clear solution, so this may be helpful for more people,

Thanks!

Comment: delete the `node_modules` folder, and re run `npm install` (or `yarn`, or whatever is your package manager's install command). Because you don't even have `@types/node` in your direct dependencies. IF this does not help, run `npm list` to see the dependency tree, and which package is pulling in the `@types/node`

Comment: Hey @c69,

I've already tried removing the `node_modules` and running again `npm install` several times, while testing different packages/versions. The reason why the @types are not being shown there is because I removed them manually for testing, the "npm install" don't put them there again.

I've now checked what you mentioned about npm list, and I've found some errors with ng2-table and another couple of deprecated modules (I'm worried about this, maybe the reason of these errors are basically that I'm using some deprecated module. I'll continue investigating.

Comment: After reviewing and fixing the issues with dependencies shown in `npm list`, I've seen that there's only 1 reference to `@types/node`:

`+-- html-webpack-plugin@4.5.0
| +-- @types/html-minifier-terser@5.1.1
| +-- @types/tapable@1.0.7
| +-- @types/webpack@4.41.28
| | +-- @types/anymatch@1.3.1
| | +-- @types/node@15.0.2 deduped`

I've tried also installing that version directly:
`    "@types/node": "15.0.2",`

Same result.

`ERROR in ../node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts:3:68 - error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.`

Comment: it is of course easy for me to suggest that.. but can you try to either remove or upgrade that module ?  maybe there was a bug in plugin - current version is much newer `5.3.1` https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got the fix, I was just messing with the package.json and testing some new dependencies, and now it works, the @types error is gone (I tried also different versions for all the @types, and these ones are the good ones for my case), this is the final package.json:

```
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "angular2-notifications": "^9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "1.6.4",
    "bootstrap-select": "1.11.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.1.4-2",
    "ng2-table": "^1.3.2", 
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/ace": "0.0.35",
    "@types/bootstrap": "3.3.33",
    "@types/bootstrap-datepicker": "0.0.6",
    "@types/bootstrap-select": "1.11.0",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
```